# Android cannot play mp3 in Chrome after using .htaccess

Tags: android, .htaccess, google-chrome

I got a website and want to let user to play/download mp3 files only when they access from download.php while all mp3 files are protected from direct access. I did it by using .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.com/download.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp3|mp4|mov)$ http://mywebsite.com/ [NC]
```

It works fine in my PC/iPad but I cannot play the mp3 in Chrome when im using android. And I test with FireFox, it works properly! 
Does anyone know what is going on and how to solve it? 
Thanks in advance.